# Securing the auth details when making a request using axios and vue.js

Tags: javascript, request, authorization, vuejs2, axios

I am making an api call using axios that requires authorisation (username and password.

I have everything working but that username and password is very accessible  when following the axios docs and having the code sat in the vue.js file, example below. How can I make this more secure?

```
  auth: {
    username: 'janedoe',
    password: 's00pers3cret'
  },
```

I understand the need for HTTPS to stop headers being intercepted, however this code sits there all the time. Am I missing a trick?

```
    created() {
        var self = this;

      axios.get(
        'https://url.com'
      , {

        auth: {
          username: 'name',
          password: 'dlkwlfdkwefhwelkfew'
        },
      })
   }
```

[Axios docs](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios)